# Is it possible to set up an account to point to another account?

Tags: anchor, rust, account, anchor-lang

I'm making an anchor program where I would like to make a user ID easily retrievable with their Pk, sequential ID or username. one way I thought is to make a PK link account (in case the seed for the ID account required the PK), which could be made from seq ID seeds or username seeds. however, this is one more hop than I'd like.

Can an account be made to point to another in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure to have fully understand what you want to achieve, but why not creating a PDA with only yhe public key as seed, and then you can store whatever data you want in your pda ? (like your own ID or username)